# Why my linux laptop suddenly hang?

Tags: xubuntu, freeze, crash, acer, debian

My linux laptop is Aspire 4738Z, and nearly it's more than 10 years old. My fan on laptop is sometimes suddenly "whoosh-whoosh-whoosh", until my laptop goes hang. Even was I open Firefox for open light websites, my laptop was hang. I was use many "lightweight" linux like Linux Mint, Debian XFCE, Xubuntu, etc. but it's same.

My RAM of laptop is 4 GB and my processor is Intel Core i3 M380. Please help me, what happened of my laptop.

This is when i run `free -h`

```
muhammadhikamzainuri@muhammadhikamz-Aspire-4738Z:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          3,5Gi       603Mi       2,4Gi        47Mi       572Mi       2,7Gi
Swap:         2,0Gi          0B       2,0Gi
```

And this is when I run `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

```
muhammadhikamzainuri@muhammadhikamz-Aspire-4738Z:~$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

And this is when I run `swapon -s`.

```
muhammadhikamzainuri@muhammadhikamz-Aspire-4738Z:~$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        2097148 0   -2
/dev/sdb                                partition   15249404    0   -3
```

Comment: Sounds like overheating. Have you tried cleaning the vents and air pathways? Laptops typically need them to be cleaned at least once or twice a year.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `swapon -s`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: I was clean my vents

Comment: @heynnema Information added.

Comment: Your swap is kind of strange. What is /dev/sdb? An external hard disk? Show me a screenshot of `gparted` when looking at /dev/sdb. Show me `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`.